# Como alterar conteúdos especifico no script de um arquivo // PHP

Tags: php, html

Gostaria de saber se alguém tem ou me consegue algum script para alterar conteúdo de um arquivo PHP em linhas especificas sem alterar as demais, pode ser  **fopen**, **fwrite** e **fclose**.

Na verdade quero, junto com dados capturados em `form`, alterar algumas `define`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O `input[name='url_site']` alteraria a linha `define('WFOX_SITE_URL', 'http://127.0.0.1/wfox');`

O `input[name='theme_site']` alteraria a linha `define('WFOX_SITE_THEME', WFOX_SITE_DIR . '/v1');`

O `input[name='name_site']` alteraria a linha `define('WFOX_SITE_NAME', 'Meu Projeto');`

Script completo `[define_log.php]`:

```
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
date_default_timezone_set('America/Fortaleza');

ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');

define('WFOX_BASE_DIR', __DIR__);
define('WFOX_SITE_DIR', WFOX_BASE_DIR . '/wfox-content');
define('WFOX_ADMIN_DIR', WFOX_BASE_DIR . '/wfox-admin');

define('WFOX_SITE_URL', 'http://127.0.0.1/wfox');
define('WFOX_SITE_ADM', WFOX_SITE_URL . '/wfox-admin');
define('WFOX_SITE_THEME', WFOX_SITE_DIR . '/v1');
define('WFOX_SITE_NAME', 'Meu Projeto');

include( WFOX_ADMIN_DIR . '/database/conn.php');
include( WFOX_ADMIN_DIR . '/api/wfox_bd_api.php');
include( WFOX_ADMIN_DIR . '/api/wfox_bd_post.php');
include( WFOX_ADMIN_DIR . '/api/wfox_bd_user.php');
include( WFOX_ADMIN_DIR . '/api/wfox_bd_upload.php');
include( WFOX_ADMIN_DIR . '/api/wfox_stats_chart.php');
```

Comment: Só uma ideia: file_get_contents , explode PHP_EOL, vai ter um array com todas as linhas, foreach percorrendo esse array e verificando se existe o nomes das constantes que você visa modificar. Caso exista, reescreve a linha montando um novo define da constante com o valor novo. Junta uma string com tudo de novo e salva o arquivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note que há diversas formas para resolver.

No exemplo abaixo, optei por algo que não fosse invasivo, modificando a estrutura corrente ou o modelo do negócio.

Apenas sugiro modificar o padrão dos nomes dos parâmetros do formulário.

Fica mais fácil se definir nomes idênticos aos das constantes.

Caso contrário, terá que criar um array que relacione tais dados, o que torna o script apenas um pouco maior e redundante.

```
<?php

/*
Dummy data.
Seria os dados do $_POST.
*/
$post['WFOX_ADMIN_DIR'] = '/outro-admin'; // simulação
$post['WFOX_SITE_URL'] = 'http://localhost'; // simulação
$post['WFOX_SITE_THEME'] = '/v2'; // simulação

/*
O path do arquivo. Recomendado usar paths absolutos.
*/
$file = __DIR__.'/a.php';

/*
Lê os resultdos, armazenando-os num array.
*/
$data = file($file);

/*
Contador da linha atual do arquivo aberto.
É usado para otimizar a leitura, evitando fazer loops inteiros para cada parâmetro.
*/
$line = 0;

/*
Quantidade de linhas do arquivo aberto
*/
$size = count($data);

/*
Itera os dados requisitados via $_POST
*/
foreach ($post as $k => $v) {
    /*
    Itera as linhas do arquivo aberto.
    É importante que a ordem dos parâmetros no post tenham a mesma ordem das linhas do arquivo.
    Caso contrário, essa rotina torna-se ineficiente.
    A vantagem aqui é otimizar, evitando fazer leitura completa do array em todas as iterações.
    Aqui, a linha continua a partir de onde parou o anterior encontrado.
    */
    while ($line < $size) {
        /*
        Procura a ocorrência da string na linha corrente
        */
        if (strstr($data[$line], '\''.$k.'\'') !== false) {
            /*
            Encontrou o padrão.
            Aplica um explode() para obter o terceiro índice que é onde encontra-se o valor que deseja alterar.
            */
            $arr = explode('\'', $data[$line]);
            $arr[3] = $v;

            /*
            Remonta a linha já com o novo valor.
            */
            $data[$line] = implode('\'', $arr);

            /*
            Interrompe o fluxo desse laço de repetição (while) e vai para o próximo do (foreach)
            */
            break;
        }
        $line++;
    }
}

/*
Salva uma cópia do conteúdo corrente.
Recomendado sempre salvar uma cópia para evitar transtornos.
Não é obrigatório. Crie a sua própria política de trabalho sobre o gerenciamento de versões.
*/
copy($file, $file.'-'.date('YmdHis'));

/*
Salva os dados modificados.
*/
file_put_contents($file, implode('', $data));
```

Leia os comentários para entender cada trecho do fluxo.

Comment: uahsuhas tinha feito algo bem similar, mas a preguiça da tão grande que não conclui... kkk VLW BROW